# Error 12 on rtl8169sc/tg3269

Tags: networking, hardware-failure

I have a pci based gigabit tplink tg3269 ethernet card which I am attempting to set up on  a P8z77V. I'm getting "This device cannot find enough free resources that it can use. If you want to use this device, you will need to disable one of the other devices on this system. (Code 12)" In device manager.

I have it on one of two PCI ports with the other one free. How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose this was made *significantly* easier by the fact that this is a modern system with very little legacy gear.

I'm was the impression that modern systems moved PCI support off the rump chipsets (which is incorrect I suspect) so, I figured the only devices which still used IRQ should be old school

I went to the UEFI config menu and rooted around - and found that the serial port was enabled. Disabling that freed up an IRQ interrupt I guess, and the card worked on reboot. While it may not work in every situation, it may be worth turning off anything else legacy on the system, rebooting and turning them back on until the device fails.